# Varbinary column not matching in SQL after Excel built query

Tags: sql, excel-formula, type-conversion, varbinary

I have an Excel file that contains a column of values

```
'0xA87CBDED7CF914342'  
'0x2C6A879A011A0959D'
```

I have built a SQL query using Excel columns as using formula below:

```
= "select * from dualsdata where udm_hapkkey in  ('"&D9&"')"
```

which translates into SQL equivalent as

```
select * 
from dualsdata 
where udm_hapkkey in ('0xA87CBDED7CF914342', '0x2C6A879A011A0959D')
```

But it won't return any results when I'm running this query. Do I need to do any sorts of conversion or casting to compare with `varbinary` types in SQL?

In SQL database table, the column `udm_hapkkey` is of type `varbinary(100)`.
Its sql server 2012 database.

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: sql server 2012 database